# how to identify page boundries in a .prn file of multiple page job

Tags: ps, printer-control-language

Can someone help me to identify the page boundaries in a multiple page job **.prn** file ?
My goal is to use a PJL command `@PJL SET MEDIASOURCE=TRAYX` at the start of every page of a multiple job file.

Where `X = page number`, for example:

- for Page 1 : `@PJL SET MEDIASOURCE=TRAY1`
- for Page 2 : `@PJL SET MEDIASOURCE=TRAY2`